# Find a universe for variables $x$, $y$, and $z$ for which the statement is true and another universe in which it is false.

Tags: logic, quantifiers

> Find a universe for variables $x, y$, and $z$ for which the statement
> $$∀x∀y((x ≠ y) → ∀z((z = x) ∨ (z = y)))$$
>
> is *true* and another universe in which it is *false*.

Is there a more efficient method than trial and error (i.e. assign universe to all real numbers, assign numbers to $x$, $y$, and $z$) ?

By universe, should I choose something like all real numbers? Or a set such as $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: See this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966345/find-a-universe-for-variables-x-y-and-z-for-which-this-statement-is-true-and-a)

Comment: I assume that the correct formula is : $∀x∀y((x \ne y) → ∀z((z = x) ∨ (z = y)))$. In this case : YES, you can assume as *universe* the set $\{ 0,1 \}$ and it will give you an example of a domain in which the formula is *true*.

Answer (score 0):

**A bit of intuition**: Consider the formula
$$∀x∀y((x ≠ y) → ∀z((z = x) ∨ (z = y)))$$

Note that it actually says

> For the universe $U$, if any arbitrary objects $x$ and $y$ are different, then any other arbitrary $z$ is either equal to $x$ or $y$.

Then we see that the referred formula will be true in any interpretation which universe $U$ has two (or one too, by vacuity) elements. It will be false otherwise.

**A bit of symbolism**:

I'm afraid of being pedant, so don't read this if my symbolism may confuse you. First we recall the notions of interpretation of a First Order language. Given a language L, and a L-structure $M$, the domain of $M$ (we shall denote it by $|M|$) can be any set, as long it is non-empy and countable (so as an answer to your question, $\{0,1\}$ is clearly allowable).

Let $M$ be an interpretation such that $M \vDash ∀x∀y((x ≠ y) → ∀z((z = x) ∨ (z = y)))$.

This means that the formula is true in $M$. We state:

> $M \vDash ∀x∀y((x ≠ y) → ∀z((z = x) ∨ (z = y)))$ iff $1\leq |M| \leq 2$

**1.** Let $|M|=1$. The formula is **true**, since $x ≠ y$ is false for every value of $x$ or $y$.

**2.** Let $|M|=2$. The formula is **true**, since $x ≠ y$ is true for every value of $x$ or $y$, but $∀z((z = x) ∨ (z = y)))$ is not false.

**2.** Let $|M|=k$, where $k\neq 1, k\neq 2$. The formula is **false**, since $x ≠ y$ is true for every value of $x$ or $y$, but obviously $∀z((z = x) ∨ (z = y)))$ is false (Pigeonhole principle).

> **Examples of structures:**
>
> > $\{0,1\}$, $\{0,2\}$, $\{3,5\}$... **true**
> >
> > $\{0,1,2\}$, $\{0,2,3\}$, $\{1,2,5\}$... **false**

Comment: Your translation "*For the universe $U$, if any arbitrary objects $x$ and $y$ are different, then any other arbitrary $z$ is either equal to $x$ or $y$*" of $∀x∀y((x ≠ y) → ∀z((z = x) ∨ (z = y)))$ is confusing because your condition sounds wrongly like you are verifying that any $(x,y)$ pair has different members, and because $x$ and $y$ should be quantified outside the conditional instead of within the antecedent, and because the adjective "other" is conflictory.

Comment: Better: For each couple, if the members are different, then every object equals at least one of them. $\quad$ Logically equivalent: For each triple, if the first two are different, then the third equals exactly one of the first two.