# find a universe for variables x, y, and z for which this statement is true and another universe in which it is false

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

Im solving a practice quesitons on quantifiers and I'm stuck with this questions
im trying to solve this question for few hours now and I really don't have a clue what to do...

The question is

> Find a universe for variables $x$, $y$, and $z$ for which the statement 
>   $$\forall x∀y((x\ne y) → ∀z((z = x) ∨ (z = y)))$$
>   is true and another universe in which it is false

Detailed explanation will be really much appreciated.
Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Is there an $x$ to much or an $\forall$ or $\exists$ missing at the beginning of the statement?

Comment: srry there should be ∀ in front of x. i edited it

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Why did you delete the question?  I have restored it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The logical negation of
$$ x\ne y\to (z=x\lor z=y)$$
is
$$x\ne y \land z\ne x\land z\ne y$$
or
$$x,y,z\text{ are three distinct objects}$$

Comment: So, $\mathbb{Z}$ can be the domain here.

Comment: thank u for ur explanation hagen. So i assume that when i make for ex x,y,z = ( 3, 3, 3) or ( 4, 4, 4) then I get true and when i make for ex x,y,z = (5,6,7) then i get false. is that correct? im working on this question for few hours and its so confusing for me..

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try $U = \emptyset, U=\{1\}, U=\{1,2\}$ and  $U=\{1,2,3\}$